# Logout from ADFS using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, adfs

I created an asp.net webform application using ADFS. Sign in and sign out work perfectly using the default method that comes with the template.

Eg of signout button method that is included in the template

```
protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Redirect to ~/Account/SignOut after signing out.
            string callbackUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Account/SignOut");

            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

I have set up a timer and upon reaching zero I tried using the above code to log the user out but it doesn't work.No error thrown.

Any suggestion how to perform logout here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is to upon timeout to call the click event of a hidden button which in turn causes the below code to run.

```
// Redirect to ~/Account/SignOut after signing out.


   string callbackUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Account/SignOut");

        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the above code that you have posted directly without the timer? and did it work?

Also, Try implementing the below code and see if it works.

```
 public void LogOut()
{          
    var module = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
    module.SignOut(false);
    var request = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(module.Issuer), module.Realm);
    Response.Redirect(request.WriteQueryString());
}
```

Comment: Module is returning null . i am getting error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is the server that is responsible for authenticating the user and for managing the user session. The website/form is just using this service. It makes sense that a site that uses this service cannot have full control over it. It would make more sense to me to log out the user from the ADFS server and have that server do the heavy lifting for you.

Note the ADFS server keeps a user logged in into ADFS server, and note that when a user requests access to a resource this manifests in an access_token. They are different things. Typically when signing somebody out with a product like identity server, in order to log out you’ll need to do two things:

- Revoke the access token
- Log out on the authentication server, (if
  that is desired, one could argue that isn’t desirable)

Note the explicit difference between session and token. You’ll notice these concepts are also in ADFS. After a quick google search you’ll find the difference between WebSSOLifetime and TokenLifetime. I would suggest configuring those to invalidate the tokens and sessions, and thereby logging the user out after an x amount of minutes.

Hope this helps.